# Convert Layout to bmp and download kotlin

Tags: kotlin, download, bitmap

How to convert a layout into bitmap and download using kotlin in android

i have tried this code but it doesn't work

```
private fun saveBitMap(context: Context, drawView: View): File {
        val pictureFileDir = File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "paymento"
        )
        //val pictureFileDir = File(cacheDir, "images")
        if (!pictureFileDir.exists()) {
            val isDirectoryCreated: Boolean = pictureFileDir.mkdirs()
            if (!isDirectoryCreated) Log.i("TAG", "Can't create directory to save the image")
        }
//        val filename: String =
//            pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + System.currentTimeMillis()
//                .toString() + ".jpg"

        val filename:String= "shared_image.png"


        val pictureFile = File(filename)
        val bitmap = getBitmapFromView(drawView)
        try {
            pictureFile.createNewFile()
            val oStream = FileOutputStream(pictureFile)
            bitmap!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, oStream)
            oStream.flush()
            oStream.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.i("TAG", "There was an issue saving the image.")
        }
        scanGallery(context, pictureFile.absolutePath)
        return pictureFile
    }

    private fun scanGallery(cntx: Context, path: String) {
        try {
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
                cntx, arrayOf(path), null
            ) { path, uri -> }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.i("TAG", "There was an issue scanning gallery.")
        }
    }
```

and inside the download button setonclickListener i tried

saveBitMap(this@Fastag,bill_recipt)

Answer (score 0):

Pass your layout as a view to this function. It will return a picture of it as a bitmap:

```
fun getBitmap(view: View): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    view.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}
```

You can also save this bitmap to the storage using this function:

```
    fun savePhotoToInternalStorageAsPng(
        context: Context,
        fileName: String,
        bmp: Bitmap
    ): Boolean {
        return try {
            context.openFileOutput("$fileName.png", BaseActivity.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .use { stream ->
                    if (!bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)) {
                        throw IOException("Couldn't save bitmap.")
                    }
                }
            true
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            false
        }
    }
```